# Screen Capture control

Tags: screen-capture

Is there any control (To use in a c# project) to record user activities and then encoding it to a video file?

Answer (score 0):

as i understand a video file is a collection of static image frames. You can use this tool's api from http://www.vcskicks.com/ScreenShotTaker.zip, which essentially shows you the mechanism of capturing the screen. So what you may have to do is, automatically capture images in a loop according to a set frame rate and then export it to a video. I'm not sure of how to create a media stream, but you have the library to do the screen capture.